# jpos.xml generation based on regedit

Tags: java, javapos

I am trying to xconfigure javapos to work with MS's Retail Peripheral Simulator. Hovever the xml generation step has gotten me to the point of angry. It's impossible to get working. Tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE JposEntries PUBLIC "-//JavaPOS//DTD//EN"
                             "jpos/res/jcl.dtd">
<JposEntries>

   <JposEntry logicalName="CashDrawer">
        <creation factoryClass="jpos.loader.JposServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="OPOSServiceObjects.Test.CashDrawer.1"/>
        <vendor name="Microsoft" url="http://microsoft.com"/>
        <jpos category="CashDrawer" version="1.11"/>
    </JposEntry> 

</JposEntries>
```

And got the error of not being able to connect to service with logical name CashDrawer... The MS simulator creates this in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\`

[image: opostree]

and I tried using some tools to add a new device.. that made CashDrawer have [image]. MockOPOSDrawer1 has [image]. Epson's JAVAPOS tool fails to launch. Is there anything else to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "MS's Retail Peripheral Simulator" a program included in the POS for.NET SDK?
If so, it is irrelevant to the OPOS registry and JavaPOS.
Furthermore, even if it is a simulator that operates as OPOS it is the same thing.

OPOS or POS for.NET can not be called from JavaPOS as much as jpos.xml changes.
The OPOS registry information is for OPOS and will not work with JCL (JavaPOS Config Loader) or JavaPOS Control Object.

You have one of the following options. However, further software development is necessary in either case.

1.Create a JavaPOS Service Object that bridges calls from JavaPOS Control Object to OPOS or POS for.NET using technology such as JNI or JNA, and use jpos.xml with the bridge JavaPOS Service Object and OPOS or POS for.NET device name and other parameters are described.

2.Give up "MS's Retail Peripheral Simulator" and create simulator as JavaPOS Service Object using Java only.

Comment: The Retail sim is a tool they provide via Dynamics for Retail, that allows.. what the title suggests - OPOS device simulation.

Comment: Based on that information, the conclusion does not change. Another alternative is to give up using Java and create an application with C# or VB. Because Visual Studio Community Edition is free to use, it is worth considering.